# Can you profit from crafting / alchemy?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Is there any money to be made from purchasing (or hoarding) low-end components like timber or twine, crafting them into better items, then selling?

Or is crafting just an inherently lossy/expensive way to obtain the best gear for yourself?

What about for potions/oils/bombs via alchemy (which at least incurs no labor charges) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crafting price of an item is about 1/10 of the purchasing price (assuming the crafting components were looted or picked up), so, it is clearly profitable to craft.

But again, selling prices are also very low compared to purchasing prices of the same item, so it really does not bring too much money. All in all, you gain something by crafting and selling, but it just does not compensate for the time and effort put into collecting of the material.

Comment: And that's assuming you picked up the components for free.  Presumably buying cloth to make solid cloth, or something like that, would be a loss?

Comment: look at the prices and do the math.. yes, you would be at a loss in the long run.

Comment: Not even alchemy creates wealth. Most herbs sell for 2 per, as do most potions and oils. Since you always use at least 2 items in alchemy, every single transmutation reduces your wealth.

Comment: I think the purpose of Alchemy not making a profit is so that Witchers would actually go hunt monsters, instead of setting up shops to sell potions.